# Shortest time for $C$ distinct objects to arrive

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Assume $N$ objects arrive with rate $\lambda_i, i =1,2,...,N$. The inter-arrival times are exponentially distributed for each object, then each object arrival process is Poisson.

Question: compute the shortest time $\tau$, where there are $C$ distinct objects arrive within duration $\tau$, and object $j$ ($j$ is a constant) is not included in the $C$ objects.

My analysis:
Let $T_i$ denote the inter-arrival time for a specific object $i$, and assume $j=1$.
There should be $C$ objects that satisfy $T_i<\tau$, and because object $j=1$ is excluded from the $C$ objects, so $T_j>\tau$.

Now my question is how to put these conditions into an equation to compute $\tau$?

---

**Edit 1**:
Here is what I think.

Define an indicator $I_i$ for object $i$. $I_i=1$ if object $i$ arrives before $\tau$, i.e., $T_i<\tau$, and $I_i=0$ otherwise. 
If we don't consider the excluded object 1, we have $\sum_{i=1}^N I_i=C$. Taking expectation on both sides, we have $\sum_{i=1}^N E[I_i]=\sum_{i=1}^N P(T_i<\tau)=C$.

Next we consider that we need to exclude the object 1, which means a condition of $T_1>\tau$ should be considered. Therefore, we rewrite the summation equation as $\sum_{i=1}^N P(T_i<\tau|T_1>\tau)=C$. Is this correct? If correct, what left is to compute the conditional probability $P(T_i<\tau|T_1>\tau)$.

One concern is, should I take $T_1>\tau$ as a condition, or as the objective. The thought above takes it as the condition. If we take it as the objective, then it should be $\sum_{i=1}^N P(T_i<\tau<T_1)=C$. I don't know which one is correct yet.

Comment: The definition of $\tau$ seems unclear to me. If $C=1$ and object $j$ is the first to arrive (which is always possible with non-zero probability by the assumptions), is $\tau$ the time when the next non-$j$ object arrives, or is $\tau$ undefined? Are we to come up with an algorithm for finding $\tau$ (which seems too easy) or a probability distribution of $\tau$?

Comment: @DavidK In the case you mentioned, $\tau$ is undefined. I should have said that $C>=2$. I know $\tau$ is a variable, but let's currently assume that $\tau$ is a constant and compute $\tau$. I will examine this assumption later.

Comment: The indicators are random variables and then so is $C$ based on your definition. But then what happens when you get the expectation?

Comment: There is no positive constant $\tau$ at which it is impossible to have received $C$ events (but not to have received $j$) and no positive constant $\tau$ at which you are certain to have received $C$ events (but not to have received $j$). How is this constant $\tau$ defined, really?

Comment: @DavidK first of all I need to tell you that tau exists. I have verified this through simulation. You can understand tau by intuition that C distinct objects arrive within the duration of tau, but object j is excluded. I am finding a way to compute tau so I don't need to get it through simulation.

Comment: @Arash what is you cannot understand about the expectation?

Comment: You have surely found _something_ via simulation, but you haven't adequately explained to us (at least to my understanding) what that thing is. Perhaps you are looking for the expected value of the distribution of the time at which your event occurs, conditioned on the fact that the event occurs at all. Until you can explain what you mean, it will be hit or miss whether anyone will guess what kind of answer you need. Good luck!

Comment: "So the definition of τ is quite clear now." The trouble is that you might be the only one to find it so.

Comment: @Did Pls take a look at my comments above, sorry that I didn't incorporate them to the question itself.

Comment: I already have, naturally. They support my own comment.

Comment: @Did I will take two steps to define $\tau$: 1) the shortest time that there are $C$ objects to arrive, starting from any time epoch. 2) the definition as in 1) except that I want object $j$ to be excluded from the $C$ objects. Other situations, like less than $C$ objects arrive before object $j$ arrives, lead to undefined $\tau$. Which step concerns you?

Comment: Again, I already have read what you wrote, naturally. The trouble is 1. that "to compute $\tau$" means nothing since one does not "compute" a random variable, and 2. that $\tau$ is not defined on the whole probability space hence one wonders what you are really after. Note that the answer below assumes that $\tau$ is deterministic, not random, and that you do not even see fit to raise the point...

Comment: @Did, My mistake. I should have said that we can treat $\tau$ as a constant if it exists. (Believe me, this question is also from a bigger system, and this assumption has been verified to be accurate.) But I did mention this in the comments replied to David K, if you have looked through, you can find it. What I am looking for is an equation to solve $\tau$ if it exists, and the equation does not have a solution if $\tau$ does not exist.

Comment: "we can treat τ as a constant if it exists" What? The only (part of a) definition of $\tau$ you provided so far, clearly indicates that $\tau$ can only be random, and now you pretend that $\tau$ is somehow a constant (no, "can be treated as a constant" means nothing mathematically speaking)? *This is not making any mathematical sense*.

Comment: @Did So I said "My mistake". You are right $\tau$ is in nature a random variable, but it can be approximated as a constant. I am looking for an equation to solve $\tau$. I need to tell you that I solve practical problems, I think about questions in a physical way, not mathematically. These question are abstractions, so I am glad that you point out my mistakes, but it's meaningless to keep excoriating me.

Comment: I excoriate nobody, only trying to understand what seem to me, at first glance, to be absurd features of your posts. Note that if your problems are, ultimately, not mathematical, posting them on a mathematical site is a dubious move. No value judgement here, only one cannot pretend that a hen is a rabbit and then be surprised that the hen does not act like a rabbit.

Comment: Can I ask that are you clear with the definition of $\tau$ now? If it's not suitable to post questions here, which site else can I seek help from? And to me this is a mathematical question, why do think it is not?

Comment: "why do think it is not (a mathematical question)?" Because you do not provide, even after having been asked for them, the mathematical features of the situation you want us to solve. Maybe you are unable to, because the setting involved is not so clear to you (which I have come to believe) or because you lack the mathematical basics (which I am convinced of, but which, oddly, may not even be the main problem here)... But anyway, the present site is made for solving mathematical questions, not to abstract them.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the number of object $i$ arrived before $\tau$ is given by $N_i(\tau)$. Note that this is Poisson distributed random variable. So the probability that at least one object arrived before $\tau$ is given by:
$$
P(N_i(\tau)\geq 1)=1-\exp(-\lambda_i\tau).
$$
and also:
$$
P(N_i(\tau)= 0)=\exp(-\lambda_i\tau).
$$
On the other hand, you actually need to compute 
$$
P(N_i(\tau)\geq 1, \text{ for at least $C$ of $i\neq 1$ and } N_1(\tau)=0)=P(N_1(\tau)=0)P(N_i(\tau)\geq 1, \text{ for at least $C$ of $i\neq 1$})\\
=\exp(-\lambda_1\tau)P(N_i(\tau)\geq 1, \text{ for at least $C$ of $i\neq 1$}),
$$
where we used the independence of the arrival times of different objects. The last one is easy to calculate using:
$$
P(N_i(\tau)\geq 1, \text{ for exactly $k$ of $i\neq 1$})=\\
\sum_{S\subset \{2,\dots,N\},|S|=k}\prod_{i\in S}(1-\exp(-\lambda_i\tau))\prod_{i\in S^c} \exp(-\lambda_i\tau).
$$
Using all that you get the probability of your desired event as a function of $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still difficult to get an expression. Please take a look at my edit to see if you can have some insights from it.